# Convert Single line of text to Person

Tags: list, visual-studio

I've done a small program to export data from Project Server to Sharepoint Server 2016, as the number of exporter field is dynamic, I had to use sql db (because CSOM doesn't allow to use other baseline than baseline 0)

So now it's pretty finish, I just have a last issue to fix
In my SQL DB, I have some person which are extracted as a string, if I tried to copy this value via my program in a field Person, I have an error message, so I'd like to know how can I pass transform this string to a person?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;  
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;  
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("SiteNameXXX");  
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListNameXXX");  
ListItem item;  
context.Load(list);  
context.ExecuteQuery();  
string name = "GET NAME FROM SQL";   
if (name != "") {  
    User userTest = context.Web.EnsureUser(testName);  
    context.Load(userTest);  
    context.ExecuteQuery();  
    testName = userTest.Id.ToString() + ";#" + userTest.LoginName.ToString();  
    ListItem item;  
    item["PeoplePickerField"] = name;  
    item.Update();  
    context.ExecuteQuery();  
}
```